# How to copy the Azure blobs to on-premise Linux server?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-logic-apps, onpremises-gateway

I need to copy the blobs to Linux server. I was able to setup a logic app and copy the blobs to Windows server but not sure how can we achieve same with linux server. ?

Answer (score 0):

Generate [sas token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview). Then `wget urlwithwith_sas_token`